# How to upload image in N2O erlang

Tags: erlang, image-uploading, nitrogen, n2o

I am setting up a new server in erlang n2o web framework, and want to upload image using #upload. How can I use upload event.

Answer (score 0):

[1]. https://github.com/synrc/sample/blob/master/src/index.erl#L14 
[2]. https://github.com/synrc/sample/blob/master/priv/static/index.htm#L7

```js
$file.progress = function onprogress(offset,total,guid,name) {
    console.log(name);
};
```